# Batch file Renamer

Tags: batch-file

```
@echo off
ren "(1) Rare Imports Exclusive.txt" "1RareImportsExclusive.txt"

set "replace="unid": 0,"
set "replaced="unid": 1,"

set "source=1RareImportsExclusive.txt"
set "target=1RareImportsExclusive1.txt"

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
(
for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^" %source%') do (
set "line=%%b"
if defined line set "line=!line:%replace%=%replaced%!"
echo(!line!
)
) > %target%

ren "1RareImportsExclusive1.txt" "(1) Rare Imports Exclusive.txt"
del "1RareImportsExclusive.txt"
endlocal
```

I have update my Original Post

I have over 1000 .txt files, and in the content of each file has a UNID code 
with random numbers

My goal is to have 1 bat file that can ignore all random numbers and 
rename the unid based on the file number

Original files 
(1) Rare Imports Exclusive.txt 
------- "unid": 2548,"

Outcome files 
(1) Rare Imports Exclusive.txt 
------- "unid": 1,"

I can only get this to work if I change all unid to 0, 
and if I make 1000 .bat files

So I make as many batch files and merge them 
This works for now

Comment: Try to add quotes to source `findstr /N "^" "%source%"`, too

Comment: Ok, I will try that, did not notice that, also is their a way to make this code  read over the file name. I just updated my question, but the file name has ( ), ex: (1) File.txt, it fails

Comment: Do you know if I do this will it work ren "(1) File.txt" "1File.txt", not in front of my computer to test at the moment, if this works then it would fix 1 problem

Comment: Yes, quoting is necessary, when the filename contains special characters like space or `(),;&`. That solves problems with  FOR and REN

Comment: Down-vote for the misleading question title as there is not a single attempt to rename any file…

Comment: @aschipfl - yes I am aware, my code was not for renaming, I was just asking a question if a batch can read around the ( ) and Jeb said with FOR and REN can do the trick

Comment: @jeb - Thanks for this findstr /N "^" "%source%" - but it didn't change anything, what was this suppose to do

Comment: @jeb - the renaming does fix the ( ) problem

Answer (score 1):

```
@ECHO Off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set "replacemain="unid": "

SET "sourcedir=u:\sourcedir\t w o"
SET "destdir=u:\destdir"

FOR /f "delims=" %%q IN ('dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\(*)*.txt"') DO (

(

 FOR /f "tokens=1 delims=()" %%j IN ("%%q") DO (
  rem %%j now has sequence number
  for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^" "%sourcedir%\%%q"') do (
   set "line=%%b"
   if defined line IF "%%b" neq "!line:unid=!" CALL :subs %%j
   echo(!line!
  )
 )

)>"%destdir%\%%q"

)
GOTO :eof

:: substitute
:subs
SET "original=%line%"
FOR /L %%s IN (0,1,9) DO set "line=!line:%replacemain%%%s=%replacemain%!"
IF "%original%" neq "%line%" goto subs
set "line=!line:%replacemain%=%replacemain%%1!"
GOTO :eof
```

As I read it, this problem has nothing to do with renaming files, but changing their contents.

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances. The listing uses a setting that suits my system.

I deliberately include spaces in names to ensure that they are processed correctly.

So, assuming that the filenames in the source directory follow the pattern `(?) filename.txt` and the required work is to replace the string `"unid": ##,` with `"unid": ?,` (where `##` is a random number and `?` is the number from the filename...

Grab the filenames to `%%q` and derive the filenumber to `%%j`.

Read and regurgitate. Detect whether the line contains `unid` etc. and further process these using `:subs`.

In `:subs`, replace the unid,etc. string followed by a digit by the string without the digit. If any change was made, repeat. Then substitute `%%j` passed as `%1` to the `:subs` routine.

--- Revision for including subdirectories.

```
@ECHO Off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

:: Significant part of string

set "replacemain="unid": "

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "destdir=u:\your results"

FOR /f "delims=" %%q IN ('dir /b /s /a-d "%sourcedir%\(*)*.txt"') DO (
 rem calculate new destination directory
 SET "newdest=%%~dpq"
 SET "newdest=!newdest:%sourcedir%=%destdir%!"
 SET "newdest=!newdest:~0,-1!"
 MD "!newdest!" 2>nul

(
 FOR /f "tokens=1 delims=()" %%j IN ("%%~nxq") DO (
  rem %%j now has sequence number
  for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^" "%%q"') do (
   set "line=%%b"
   if defined line IF "%%b" neq "!line:unid=!" CALL :subs %%j
   echo(!line!
  )
 )
)>"!newdest!\%%~nxq" 

)
GOTO :eof

:: substitute
:subs
SET "original=%line%"
FOR /L %%s IN (0,1,9) DO set "line=!line:%replacemain%%%s=%replacemain%!"
IF "%original%" neq "%line%" goto subs
set "line=!line:%replacemain%=%replacemain%%1!"
GOTO :eof
```

You would need to change the values assigned to `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances. The listing uses a setting that suits my system.

I deliberately include spaces in names to ensure that the spaces are processed correctly.

First, addition of `/s` in the `dir` command to cause scanning of subdirectories. This means that `%%q` will contain the absolute filename of each file that fits the mask `(*)*.txt`.

Since the destination directory may now change, `newdest` is calculated by replacing the value of `sourcedir` with the value of `destdir` and removing the final `\` character since `%%~dpq` will deliver a `\`-terminated string.

The directory thus calculated is then created with a `md` instruction, and any objection from the system (as it's likely the directory already exists) is discarded with `2>nul` (send error messages nowhere).

Since `%%q` originally contained the filename only, we need to specifically select the name and extension of `%%q` (`%%~nxq`) when calculating `%%j`.

Since `%%q` contains the absolute filename, we remove the `%sourcedir%` from the file-read loop using `%%a`.

Finally, the destination file needs to be constructed from the calculated `newdest` and the name+extension of the sourcefile.

--- Re-revision

```
@ECHO Off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

:: Significant part of string

set "replacemain="unid": "

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "destdir=u:\your results"

:: for tracking directory-changes
SET "lastdir="

SET /a serial=1

FOR /f "delims=" %%q IN ('dir /b /s /a-d "%sourcedir%\(*)*.txt"') DO (
 rem use following line to restart serial number for each file
 REM SET /a serial=1
 if "!lastdir!" neq "%%~dpq" (
  rem use following line to restart serial number for each directory
  REM SET /a serial=1
  rem calculate new destination directory
  SET "newdest=%%~dpq"
  SET "lastdir=%%~dpq"
  SET "newdest=!newdest:%sourcedir%=%destdir%!"
  SET "newdest=!newdest:~0,-1!"
  MD "!newdest!" 2>NUL
 )

(
 rem %%j will acquire sequence number for filename pattern (*)*.txt
 REM FOR /f "tokens=1 delims=()" %%j IN ("%%~nxq") DO SET "serial=%%j"
 rem use following line to select a random serial number for each file
 REM CALL :randsn

 for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^" "%%q"') do (
  set "line=%%b"
  if defined line IF "%%b" neq "!line:unid=!" CALL :subs 
  echo(!line!
 )
)>"!newdest!\%%~nxq" 

)
GOTO :eof

:: substitute
:subs
SET "original=%line%"
FOR /L %%s IN (0,1,9) DO set "line=!line:%replacemain%%%s=%replacemain%!"
IF "%original%" neq "%line%" goto subs
set "line=!line:%replacemain%=%replacemain%%serial%!"
SET /a serial+=1
GOTO :eof

:randsn
SET /a serial=%RANDOM%
:: Ignore selections 30000..32767 for even distribution
IF %serial% geq 30000 GOTO randsn
:: Use 10000 for 4-digit maximum, 1000 for 3, 100 for 2
SET /a serial=serial %% 10000
:: Use the following line if 0 is not allowed
IF %serial%==0 GOTO randsn
GOTO :eof
```

This provides a choice of how the number is calculated.

To activate any particular option, change the `REM` in the line following the comment to   (nothing). It would probably be insane to try to activate more than one option at any one time. To deselect an option, put the `REM`  keyword back in place.

The random option will generate a random 1-4-digit number. There is absolutely no guarantee whatever that the numbers inserted in this case will be unique.

To allow the routine to operate on *any* file in the tree, simply change the filemask `(*)*.txt` to some other filemask, noting that the derivation of sequence number for filenames that do not start `(number)` via `%%j` would then become nonsense, so the setting of `serial` from `%%j` should be de-activated with a `rem` statement (as posted)

Comment: I would replace `'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\(*)*.txt"'` with `'findstr /mrc:"%replacemain:"=\"%" "%sourcedir%\(*)*.txt"'` to avoid processing files that don't contain the search string.

Comment: Perfect Thank you everyone for this help I will put this together and test

Comment: @Magoo can you explain the t w o

Comment: Simply a standard directoryname I use to ensure that batches work with directorynames containing spaces.

Comment: @Stephan - Thank you very much, and I have saved all my notes, just wanted to let you 
 know that all files that I'm working with have unid to find, so we're good, once again Thank you

Comment: @Magoo - Thank you - Question reading your explanation - Do I need to change anything in the update code, I saved it to a bat file and ran it, I saw the cmd open close and nothing happen

Comment: All file name will start with (1) numerically so from (1) to (1000), and then the file name, so it looks like this (1) File.txt, all Unid inside have random numbers and look like this "unid": 1524, I'm still learning how to read FOR with delims

Comment: When you use the point-click-and-giggle method of executing a batch, the batch window will often close if a syntax-error is found. You should instead [open a 'command prompt'](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/ ) and run your batch from there so that the window remains open and any error message will be displayed. If you have retyped rather than copy-pasting the code (obviously, you need to change the source and destination directories) then check for transcription errors. Use an editor like `editplus` or `notepad++` as `notepad` is known to introduce errors by trying to format the code.

Comment: If you change `@echo off` to `@echo on`, then each command will be displayed before it is executed and you may be able to see error messages if any are generated.

Comment: @Magoo - how do I run it from cmd open, I copy the directory where the file is located this is the location C:\Users\user\Desktop\File UNID\Unid.bat, and I couldn't get it to run the bat, I opened the cmd with admin as well

Comment: @Magoo - I cant' seem to figure out were the problem is, can't get the code to work

Comment: Need more information. Have you followed the guide 3 comments above and created a "command prompt" icon or are you attempting to persist with double-clicking the batch file? What happens? Describe any messages displayed.

Comment: @Magoo I right click the bat ran it like admin, I double clicked and nothing, I opened cmd and nothing, I did this  C:\Users\user\Desktop\File UNID\Unid.bat, and nothing, not sure what you mean cmd icon

Comment: I can't see what values you have assigned `sourcedir` and `destdir`, nor what precise response is shown on the screen. Try inserting a line `echo %%q&pause` directly after the line that starts `FOR /f "delims=" %%q I...` and describe results. Try changing `@echo off` to `@echo on` and see whether that reveals anything. "Nothing" is not possible.  "System locks up" is a something. "get new prompt" is a something. Give away the clicking idea for debugging - run from the command prompt to see the results of commands.

Comment: @Magoo So sorry I did not know I could edit the black screen that was placed under my screen, ok so you asked what sourcedir is assigned - do you mean something like this SET "sourcedir=u:\C:\Users\New User\Desktop\Rare Imports\t w o" - this would be the folder my files are found

Comment: @Magoo Also I have updated my original post to show what I have put together that works, but takes time to build what I needed it to do.

Comment: @magoo like this-  FOR /f "delims=" %%q IN ('dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\(*)*.txt"') DO ( echo %%q&pause

Comment: `SET "sourcedir=u:\C:\Users\New User\Desktop\Rare Imports\t w o"` is incorrect. I do not know what the actual location is. As I usually remark,  but have omitted to say on this occasion (corrected) `u:\sourcedir\t w o` is a test directory on my machine which deliberately includes spaces in the name to test whether the routine acts as expected when spaces are present in a name. In your case, you should change the command to `SET "sourcedir=C:\Users\New User\Desktop\Rare Imports"`, assuming `C:\Users\New User\Desktop\Rare Imports` is the directory-location on your machine.

Comment: In comments, using " ` " (backtick character) on each end of a code string will highlight the code. If you don't use that, `*)*` is rendered to an italic `)` by markdown. The code is correct, but since `sourcedir` was set to an incorrect value, it would not have found any filenames.

Comment: @Magoo - OMG!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! I see now my mistake, I thought I had to keep the =u and the T W O in those sourcedir and destdir - It works - I wonder if I can make this read in subfolders, since I also have them in a ton of folders, right now I move them from 1 folder to the Dir folder - I run .bat and then I move them back a folder at a time, can we add a code to this to look in all sub folders, starting with a Folder Name called Rare Imports

Comment: @magoo question what would I need to change if I had 1000 unid inside of 1 Rare Import file, this time it would need a number sequence. All unid have random numbers, but all would change numerically starting from 1 to 1000, in this case no file number would be used, just 1 rare.txt with 1000 unid context

Comment: @magoo what I have are 2 sets of files. 1 rare.txt file with 1000 unid found in the context, and the others are extracted 1000 files, using the batch that was given works great for all 1000 extracted files, what do I need to change to change all unid inside 1 text file

Comment: I hope I've fixed the instructions properly. No doubt others have encountered the same problem, though this is the first mention. I've left the original as-is otherwise the comments would make little sense.

Comment: We seem to have very mobile goalposts for this question. I am confused by `1000 unid`. Does this mean a literal text `1000 unid` in the file or are there 1000 occurrences of `unid somenumber`within one file? Is this new requirement to replace each `unid somenumber` with `unid anincrementingserialnumber`?

Comment: @Magoo - Yes we also have 1 Rae.txt files with a million context inside, and inside this 1 file I have over 1000 Unid and they all represent something inside this file, but the numbers is generates are all random and we need to change all inside this 1 rare.txt file, so it would find the first unid and repalce the random numbers with 1, then it finds the second unid and replaces it with 2, and so  on, also none of the UNIND share the same line, they all have their own line

Comment: @Magoo - --- Revision for including subdirectories. - This works great, but for some reason it stops at one folder, So I have Main folder\Folder1\Folder2\ and inside folder 2 I have 2 folders Folder A and B, the code scans Folder A and does what it needs, but Folder B gets skipped, Now I would like to know am I allowed to make a video and post the link here, so that I can show you what  it does, I feel that we can see better things with visual on what happens when testing

Comment: @Magoo - What do you mean by this "We seem to have very mobile goalposts for this question"

Comment: @ Magoo - OK I found the error on why it would skip Folder B, my files in Folder B did not have the (1) in front of the file name - The code will skip any txt file that this code (*) *.txt does not match, My folder B had Filename (1).txt, once I change it to (1) Filename.txt it copied everything in both folders, I am trying to implement a rename or a move command so that it can move to original location and replace the originals, to avoid moving them from their original folders

Comment: @ Magoo - OK so I found a way to work with this, instead of tring to work in the same source since it does not copy and transfer correctly, I will double my folders, so I will have this - Folder1\Sub1\Sub2\Subs3 Copies, and Folder2\Sub1\Sub2\Subs3 Original, all I have to do is set the directory to Source Folder1, and Designation Folder2, and it will overwrite all the originals with the corrected data, and in any case if anything goes wrong, I still have the Folder1 copies of all my originals.. so nothing to lose, and if I don't have the created folders in Folder2, it gets generated

Comment: @Magoo - this code is killer, this unid changer can do so much more, with simple renaming of files to have the (?) filename.txt, I can change pretty anything... This code literally saved we months of work, down to 10 minutes, I have over 10,000 files that carry the unid, and I have manually finished 2500 files, I renumbered them manually and I have been at this for since August, now my work is done, but could use your help with one more thing - this code under Revision for including subdirectories - needs the (?) to work how will this work with filenames that don't have (?) filename.txt

Comment: @Magoo - I am very grateful that you were able help me with this - I've been trying for month to find this method, trying everything, I'm not skilled enough, hopefully one day I can join your community and return the favor to others. So the last 2 projects I need help with are very similar jobs, same as code above 1000 .txt files, but without the (?) in the file name, the other will be 1 filename.txt, that carries 1000 unid inside mixed with content, both need to change the unid from random numbers to start from 1 to infinity

Comment: @Magoo - Hey I'm trying to add these code to a batch menu and I can't figure out why - on top of my page I already have #echo off - so I have this - IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 2 (
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION - all I want is to press 2 and launch it, is this code unable to do this, or can you help me launch the batch using another patch, this would be the directory for the UNID.bat SET "sourcedir=C:\Users\New User\Desktop\Main Color Workstation\Originals" - or we can leave it here Main Color Workstation\Originals

Comment: How can I add a black screen down here link you'll do it

Comment: @Magoo - I have updated my original post with a new setup, it's under my original request

Comment: I believe that we have to call a halt to this ever expanding problem. Introducing menus adds a level of complexity that needs to be tackled in a new question. Parenthesising a block of code introduces yet more problems. Conventionally, menus are constructed by using the "choice" command with each errorlevel to execute a goto to a label. There are many examples on Stack Overflow, just use the search facility.

Comment: @Magoo - Thank you all works well, saved me so much time, and I figured out how to use the call function, so for now I have 1 menu where I press 1, press2 and so on, and they call on the other batch files, so I'm good on the this We can close this out as answered. Everything provided is what I needed to get this never ending problem I had to move faster, now I can finish my work 100 times faster - Thank you very much